# query attribute isnt working fine in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database

[image: Dataset]

This is the dataset i am working with

```
 mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").assign(pick_time = mast_df.Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+mast_df.Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float")-mast_df.Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+mast_df.Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float"))
```

getting the error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

While the following code :

```
mast_df = mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')")
mast_df.assign(
    pick_time = mast_df.Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+mast_df.Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float")
    -mast_df.Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+mast_df.Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float"))
```

isn't giving any error

Seems like the query in the first code isn't working fine. Even though i have written to omit them. Actually i have replaced the null values with "0:-:0" such that later i can replace them. With some time.

Edit : Finally done it through lambda function. Here is the code :

```
mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").assign(
    pick_time = lambda df_ : df_.Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+
    df_.Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float")-
    df_.Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+
    df_.Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float"))
```

Comment: please provide your data as a reproducible form

Answer (score 0):

In the first code when you write 'mast_df.Time_Order_picked' you select from all database(not from the queried database). In the second code mast_df is now the queried database(without the null values, because of that worked)
If you have to write the second code in one line, you have to:

```
mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").assign(pick_time = mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").Time_Order_picked.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float")-mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[0].astype("int")*60+mast_df.query("(Time_Orderd != '0:-:0') & (Time_Order_picked != '0:-:0')").Time_Orderd.str.split(":",expand = True)[1].astype("float"))
```

but that will do the query 4 times

Comment: Okay...but it shud work right...thats the point of chaining the methods..I have gone through the book and it shud work fine AFAIK..

Comment: Yes, my one line method should work fine. Your one line doesnt work because .query() doesnt modify mast_df, just return a new (in your code unused) object. So you need to use the returned object

Comment: Finally done it using Lambda functions : Edited the question

Comment: Just for curiosity. Has any advantaje the last function against do in at least two lines?

Comment: I think yes. When compared with your line of code. In your code querying is done 4 times. By using lambda function we are only querying it only once and then creating the additional column. I am not sure but i think when we use them on big data we can see the one with lambda function will take lesser time than the one written by you..

Comment: Yes, the lambda code Is better that my line of code. But i think the best is use multiple lines, like the two line code in your questions. Is the same but with more readability